# Share managed resources in tests (zio tests)

Tags: managed, zio, zio-test

I'm binding an `HttpRoute` and testing it.
That occurs inside a `ZManaged` context.

Yet I need to `use` it for each test, which is very resource inefficient.

Is there a way run many labeled tests inside a `ZManaged` context?

Comment: Have a look at `.provideSomeLayerShared` and `.provideCustomLayerShared`

Comment: maybe you can leverage ZManaged#zio method somehow for this.

Comment: @paulpdaniels. Your answer is correct. It worked. You should post it as an answer